# Ask for client certificate IIS7.5 when accessing certain folders

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, iis-7.5, client-certificates

We've an ASP.NET MVC4 app where there is a part which should be secured through client certificates.

When anyone wants to connect to this part of the app, browsers should ask them for a client certificate, once they select it, our server will get it, check it's validity and show the content.

Ok, I'm getting trouble with the select certificate part. Before setting it just to one folder on views content, I'm trying to configure this on the global app.

I've set SSL to be required, and also set require client certificates on SSL Configuration on apps configuration on IIS.

I've enabled the iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication (although I've set no mapping yet)

When I try to access the app both, Firefox and Chrome, return a 403 forbidden error, stating that I have no access to the app with the credentials provided.

I've a client certificate installed on my local machine and the CA who created this certificate as a trusted root certificate on server local machine.

I'm not being prompted for certificate.
If I uncheck the "require" from client certificates on SSL Settings, I can access the app through https.

This is the first time I work with client certificates, so it's being a bit confusing and maybe I'm not giving enough info. Feel fre to ask for further info on the comments.

**EDIT:** I've exported the client certificate, copied it to the server and checked it there. The certificate shows as valid and every element in the certification chain seems to be recognized in the server.

I've checked IIS logs also, and the error I'm getting is 403.7, so the certificate is not being issued to the server or it's invalid.

Now... I've checked that the certificate is valid on the server, it's correctly installed on the client but it's not getting to the server or is not beign validated there... what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I've found the problem, it's related to the buffer size reserved for the list of trusted certification authorities.

Check this kb article:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/933430

TL DR; To solve the problem just add a new entry in the registry at:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL

named SendTrustedIssuerList as a DWORD value with value 0.

This way, the server won't send the trusted certification authorities list, so browsers will display the complete list of certificates to the user.